# Is there a way to "escape" HTML styles in AMP script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, css, content-builder

We have some basic content blocks with AMP script that we use in our emails (ContentBlockByID). The following AMP script is used:

```
%%[
if @XXXX == 'XXXX')  then
set @text = 'Some text'

else 
set @text = 'Some other text'

endif
]%%
```

Now we have a text link with some inline CSS. Like this:

```
set @text = 'Some <a href="#" style="font-family:'FONT', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px; color: #27324C">text</a>
```

This gives us a problem because of the single quotes in the font family. Is there a way to fix this? I can not convert it to double quotes because this font in our base CSS only works with single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape quotes in Ampscript by "duplicating" them, hence this solution will fix it for you:

```ampscript
set @text = 'Some <a href="#" style="font-family:''FONT'', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px; color: #27324C">text</a>'
```

Comment: Yes it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the html block and AMPscript block like this

```
%%[
if @XXXX == 'XXXX'  then
]%%
Some <a href="#" style="font-family:'FONT', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px; color: #27324C">text</a>

%%[else]%%
<!-- put your other text here -->

%%[endif]%%
```

Or you can put one more single quotes on the font name
Try this:

```
%%[

set @text = 'Some <a href="#" style="font-family:''FONT'', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px; color: #27324C">text</a>'

]%%

%%=v(@text)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
set @text = "Some <a href='#' style='font-family:'FONT', Arial, sans-serif;font-size: 16px; color: #27324C'>text</a>"
```

I've inverted the use of single and double quotes. Plus, you were missing a double quote at the end.

More info here: https://ampscript.guide/string-constants/